# How to fix the Break Beam Sensor programming issue that says "USB Device Disabled"?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, usb, breadboard

I am trying to use the [Adafruit Metro Mini](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2590) as Arduino (can be used the same way) to program an [IR Break Beam sensor](https://learn.adafruit.com/ir-breakbeam-sensors) and a stepper motor. I connected the beam sensor to the breadboard and plugged the Arduino into my computer. But  my MAC pops up with the notification:

> "USB Device Disabled - Unplug the device using too much power to
>   re-enable USB Devices."

What is the problem causing the issue? Did I short circuit something? I attached photos to my circuit to the post.

[image] 
[image]

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: "*USD* device"?? Are you sure that shouldn't be "USB device"? Does the problem still occur if you take the Metro Mini out of the breadboard?

Answer (score 1):

The stepper motor driver is installed with the error (shifted) to the breadboard.

The electrolytic capacitor at the output of the voltage stabilizer in reverse polarity.

Power to  Adafruit Metro Mini is put in inverse polarity ...